# Using Xresources configurations when running x client with additional property

Tags: shell, terminal, colors, xterm

I setup a `.Xresources` file:

```
xterm*background: #2b2c2b
xterm*foreground: beige
```

and automatically load `.Xresources` on system start using `.xinitrc`:

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge -I$HOME ~/.Xresources
```

Now if I run `xterm -name test` it does not apply the color definitions from my custom resource file. Are there a other options to create a setup which effects my color definitions except to a custom script `/usr/bin/my-xterm`:

```
xterm -fg beige -bg '#2b2c2b -name $1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource setting like `xterm*background: …` applies to the *instance name* `xterm`. The instance name is what you select with the `-name` option to xterm and other applications that follow the X convention. If you use a non-default instance name, then your setting does not apply.

To apply a setting to all instances, use the class name instead of an instance name. The convention (which I don't remember seeing violated) is that instance names start with a lowercase letter while class names start with an uppercase letter. Both use mid-name capitalization to mark word boundaries. For applications whose name starts with X, whether it counts as a separate word varies. In the case of xterm, the class name is `XTerm`. In general, to determine the class name, look it up in the application's documentation, or check a window with a tool like `xprop`: the `WM_CLASS` property contains the instance name followed by the class name.

So if you want your resources to apply to any xterm, use

```
XTerm*background: #2b2c2b
```

You should probably make that resource more specific, because it applies to anything that xterm displays unless overridden. To apply only to the main text area, use

```
XTerm.vt100.background: #2b2c2b
```